# Unable to locate package linux-image-extra-4.15.0-46-generic

Tags: apt

I'm trying to install docker on 16.04, but when running

```
sudo apt-get install -y linux-image-extra-"$(uname -r)"
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-extra-4.15.0-46-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-image-extra-4.15.0-46-generic'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-extra-4.15.0-46-generic'
```

from https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ I understand there is only linux-image-extra-4.15.0-**15**-generic and linux-**modules**-extra-4.15.0-46-generic

which one should I install?

`uname -r` returns `4.15.0-46-generic`

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to install `extra` for this kernel? It is wrong. Where did you get this command? `modules-extra` should be installed already.

Comment: It is on my installation script, I'm pretty sure it was on the docker installation guide (https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) few (or maybe more than few) months ago. can you elaborate why it is wrong?

Comment: Just ignore this line.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel you're trying to install isn't from xenial, but from bionic 18.04.02 LTS release. 4.15.0-46-generic is probably a backport from bionic to xenial ...

https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/kernel/linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-46-generic . Modules-extra, not image-extra ...

The latest kernel from xenial is:

```
mtodorov@croartia:~$ uname -r
4.4.0-142-generic
```

https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/kernel/linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic, however,  appears as supported.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/kernel/linux-image-extra-4.4.0-141-generic is available in the repository [security].

Comment: This is the kernel I got on new server installation (16.04.6 LTS)

Comment: This is a correct kernel HWE.

Comment: My installation of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has linux-image-extra-4.4.0-141-generic but not linux-image-extra-4.15.0-46-generic ...